# get latitude and longitude html js

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i have to do something and i have already a part of work.
I want to insert longitude(long) and latitude(lat) in mysql database.
 found this code who gives me lon and lat

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
            "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }
</script>

</body>
```

This code print long and lat, that i want is to get long and lat in php and run sql query behind.

Comment: Use `ajax` to get those coords to your backend

Comment: I don't know how to use ajax.but if you have an example i can try to do it.

Comment: We don't, but Google will give you zillions of examples about how to send data to a server.

Answer (score 1):

Using ajax you can save latitude and longitude into the database. For this update your script as given below.

```
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

    saveData(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

}

function saveData(latitude,longitude){
        $.ajax({
        url: 'save_data.php', // Script to save latitude and longitude
        type: 'GET', 
        data: { latitude : latitude, longitude : longitude },
        dataType: "json",     
        success: function(result) {
            //Return result
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is my save_data.php good? <?php
/* simple example */
$lat=$_GET['latitude'];
$long=$_GET['longitude'];
echo "$lat";
?>

Comment: Yes..make sure you are getting GET variable values.

Comment: Using GET to save data? What about using POST instead ?